# How to dismiss iOS 14 datePicker modal?

Tags: ios14, xcuitest

My development team has implemented the new iOS 14 date picker in the "compact" style, which pops a modal on top of our application. It doesn't have any controls to dismiss. As a user, I can tap outside the modal, which I figured `application.windows.firstMatch.tap()` would simulate well. It does when I'm debugging, but when running regularly, it is also dismissing the view behind the modal. Kind of confusing as to why it would act differently, but :shrug:

I've suggested we move to the "inline" style, but may not get my way (it's a better UX in our use-case anyway). Is anyone successfully dismissing these without unintended consequences?

[image: "Compact datePicker"]

Comment: It looks like I'm getting my way with the switch to inline, but still curious to hear what has worked for others.

Comment: Date Picker is presented as a model view controller so it can be dismissed using:   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Not in XCUITest.

Comment: For XCUITest you need to use mock class or flag value.

Answer (score 3):

This worked on the iPhone.

```
@IBAction func dateChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    model.date = datePicker.date
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Maybe if this dimisses too much on iPad you need to set `definesPresentationContext = true` on your view controller?

Comment: Thanks. Will take me a dew days to circle back to this, but will thumbs up if it works.

Comment: Great, it works, after selecting the date we can hide the picker's calendar controller `_UIDatePickerIOSCompactViewController` using simple `dismiss()`!

Comment: Is it working when user is typing the time in case mode is dateAndTime?